# Python/Git/Azure Repos - Read remote file without Pulling/Downloading

Tags: python, git, azure, azure-repos

Given an Azure Repos git repo/file url, is it possible to read a single file located in the git repo straight into memory **without having to** pull the whole repo? Specifically using the Python `git` library.

Comment: Yes, you can download a specific file from this link: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[YOUR_USERNAME]/[YOUR_REPO_NAME]/master/[YOUR_FILENAME]`

Comment: Interesting, so this if I do a Python `requests.get` (with the correct credentials) to githubusercontent.com I should be able to download the file? I need this for Azure Repos

Comment: It works in Github for public repos. Haven't tries for private repos